# Query that countes pairs with same values depending on third column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, qsqlquery

I have three columns: `Team_Code`, `ID`, `times_together`.
I'm trying to count how many times ID's have the same "Team_Code" and add times_together to it.
In other words- I'm trying to write all the pairs of one column, check how many times they have the same value in other raw, and add third raw to it.

The simple way to ask this question is picture so:
[image]

Values can appear twice (for example
1110 with 8888
and then
8888 with 1110).

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what you are looking for specifically. I see that users (differentiated by their ID's) can have the same team code, and you want to count how many people they are linked with with that team code. So in your output, you are showing that ID 2220 is liked once with 1110, 8888 is linked once with 1110 but why is 2220 linked 11 times with 8888? If you could, show us the mathematics behind how you got to those times_together outputs, we would have a better understanding of what you are looking for.

Comment: it's hard to understand why the output for `2220 - 8888` is `11` (while I doubt it should be `12` or `6`). The first addition you made is `5+5` but why that is not applied for `1+1` (which will sum up `12`)? If there is not any addition `5+5` then I expect you added it as `5+1` (so the output should be `6`) (`5` times in the same team with code of `433` and `1` time in the same team with code of `111`).

Comment: I'm SORRY! will edit in a minute. the output should be 6. Thats because 8888 have been with 2222 in Team_Code 433 five times, and in Team_Code 111 one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could self join the table on `team_code` and sum the `times_together`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, SUM(t1.times_together)
FROM   mytable t1
JOIN   mytable t2 ON t1.team_code = t2.team_code AND t1.id != t2.id
```

If you want to make sure each pair only appears once, you could add a condition to always take the lower id on the left:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, SUM(t1.times_together)
FROM   mytable t1
JOIN   mytable t2 ON t1.team_code = t2.team_code AND t1.id < t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this self-joining SQL which takes all possible *ID* pairs (but only where the first is smaller than the second), and uses a `CASE` to sum the *times_together* when the persons played in the same team:

```
select     t1.id,
           t2.id,
           sum(case when t1.Team_Code = t2.Team_Code 
                then t1.times_together
                else 0
           end) times_together
from       t as t1
inner join t as t2 
        on t1.id < t2.id
group by   t1.id, t2.id
order by   1, 2
```

Output in the example case is:

```
|   id |   id | times_together |
|------|------|----------------|
| 1028 | 1110 |              0 |
| 1028 | 2220 |              0 |
| 1028 | 8888 |              0 |
| 1110 | 2220 |              1 |
| 1110 | 8888 |              1 |
| 2220 | 8888 |              6 |
```